# With Xamarin Forms, using x:Static inside x:Key= inside App.xaml not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

So I'm writing a Xamarin Forms app and I'm attempting to eliminate any magic strings throughout the app. One of the places that always seems to end up with hard coded strings is the App.Xaml file, specifically the x:Key attributes of anything placed in it.

For example for the entry:`<Color x:Key="GrayColor">#8f8e8e</Color>` the string "GrayColor" is hard coded and then must be typed exactly wherever it's used.

My idea is to create a global Constants class and store the keys in there. Something like:

```
public static class Constants
{
    public const string GrayColor = "GrayColor";
}
```

This works for accessing the color when setting a property in the codebehind on an object like: `BackgroundColor = (Color)Application.Current.Resources[Constants.GrayColor]`and in the Xaml of the view like: `TextColor="{StaticResource Key={x:Static helpers:Constants.GrayColor}}"`.

However when I attempt to update the App.Xaml entry with `<Color x:Key="{x:Static helpers:Constants.GrayColor}">#8f8e8e</Color>`, I get the error `System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` as soon as I fire up the app.

I've done some poking around and I can't tell if using x:Static inside x:Key is even supported or not. Can anybody point me the correct direction? My complete code is shown below:

The App.Xaml class:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.Shared.App"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"             
         xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Test.Shared.Helpers"
         xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>           
        <Color x:Key="{x:Static helpers:Constants.GrayColor}">#8f8e8e</Color>            
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The Constants class:

```
namespace Test.Shared.Helpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains constants that are used throughout the app.
    /// </summary>
    public static class Constants
    {        
        public const string GrayColor = "GrayColor";        
    }
}
```

And the View where it's used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Grid x:Class="Test.Shared.Controls.CustomView"
      xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:Test.Shared.Helpers"
      x:Name="This">

<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".7*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".15*" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<StackLayout Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.Column="1"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
             Spacing="15"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=DisplayImageSource}" />
    <Label FontSize="14.5"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference This}, Path=DisplayText}"
           TextColor="{StaticResource Key={x:Static helpers:Constants.GrayColor}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: hrm, just putting it out there, but i wouldn't generally class a resource name as a magic string, this seems like a lot of work for little gain, also i doubt this is even possible

Comment: Agreeing above comment, it looks like you have to do more work/longer string on each use. The constant values that you set out on App level, they are less likely to change if it does than should change the value not the key. This is like writing css on web, you wouldnt define css file and let js keep the constant name of the css and use it..

Comment: I figured this was case. Thanks guys. I'll leave the question open just in case someone stumbles across an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like x:Key accepts strings only. It doesn't support markup extensions. However, you still can get rid of magic strings. Add your color resource to the resource dictionary from the code behind of the App.xaml.cs like this:

```
Resources.Add(Constants.GrayColor, Color.FromHex("#8f8e8e"));
```